# Dragonfly masked DH

Tags: key-exchange, passwords, side-channel-attack

I was looking at Dragonfly key exchange protocol [RFC 7664](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7664), and it seems to make use of masked Diffie-Hellman in the final part. Generating two random numbers less than group order $q$, $m$, and $r$ and outputting $P^{-m}$ and $m+r$ where $P$ is derived from the password. (I am omitting the analogous ECDH part). I did a little work to see that it is computationally equivalent to CDH, so it is not about basing it on a harder problem.

Is it to protect from some side-channel attacks? If so, what type of side-channel attack is that which works with normal DH but not on Dragonfly? I expect timing attacks on $p$ and $m$ to be equivalent, so I don't think it's about timing attacks on the private exponent. Or is it some side-channel attack targeted towards finding $P$ to facilitate offline dictionary attacks?

As a side note, I don't see any defense from a man-in-the-middle attack by someone who knows the password in the original protocol or has its variants (like WPA3 is using).

Comment: This is an old unanswered question of mine. Anyone see this?